# can't run selenium as root

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run selenium on google chrome

```
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    chromedriver_directory = f'{cwd}/chromedriver'
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_directory, options=chrome_options)
```

as root I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 260, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 239, in main
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_directory, options=chrome_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

but as non-root user the program runs fine

Comment: Where is chrome driver resides in your system ? where is Google chrome installed ?

Comment: google-chrome: /usr/bin/google-chrome /usr/share/man/man1/google-chrome.1.gz
, chromedrivrer in the same directory as the python script